# how to get emoji from whatsapp chat and and send that emoji to sender by python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp, emoji

This is the code.
How to get emoji from whatsapp chat and and send that emoji to sender by python selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions  


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r'https://web.whatsapp.com/')
searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='side']//div//div//label//div//div[@contenteditable='true']")))
searchbox.send_keys('ENTER YOUR CHAT NAME')
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
input("Enter any key :")
chats = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("message-in")
if len(chats) > 6:
    chats = chats[-6:]
for i in range(0, len(chats)): 
    try:           
        chat = chats[i].find_element_by_class_name("_24wtQ") 
        emojiclass = chats[i].find_elements_by_class_name("_3ExzF")
        emoji = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img").get_attribute("src")
        print(emoji) 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: plz help me anyone

Comment: Are you trying to select emojis from the incoming messages texts there?

Comment: yes yes i actually used that method for text meassges do you know another method ? someone suggested me to use unicode utf8 .but i dont have much knowledge about that .can you plz help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no change in web element there if it contains text, emoji or text and emoji.
It is a text message format.
So you can not distinguish according to element class name or any other attribute if it contains emoji or not.
All you can do is to extract (each) text message and then check if that text string contains emoji or not.
**UPD**
This XPath will give you all the incoming messages emojis:

```
//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB']
```

And this will give you the last incoming emoji in the conversation:

```
(//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB'])[last()]
```

If you have to get the entire last message in including that emoji, not just the emoji itself, try this

```
(//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB'])[last()]/..
```

or this

```
(//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB'])[last()]/../..
```

Comment: but that gives error when there is an emoji or text+emoji ,as i seen in inspect elements emoji link is in .png format . i use this code for getting last text message from sender             'lasttext = chats[i].find_element_by_class_name("_3-8er").text ' 'print(lasttext)'

Comment: plz help me , can you give me code to get last text message from sender which has both text + emoji? . it will be very helpful

Comment: bro its not working , your first xpath is printing empty list ,second,third,fourth xpaths are giving nosuchelementexception

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions `

Comment: Maybe you are missing a wait before that to make the page loaded?

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\PRANAV PATIL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(r'https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input('enter any key:')
searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='side']//div//div//label//div//div[@contenteditable='true']")))
searchbox.send_keys('ENTER YOUR SENDER'S NAME')
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
input('enter any key:')`

Comment: `try:
    texta = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB']")
    print(texta)
    print(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
try:
    textu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB'])[last()]")
    print(textu)
    print(2)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`

Comment: `try:
    texti = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB'])[last()]/..")
    print(texti)
    print(3)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
try:
    textg = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='_1gL0z']//div[contains(@class,'message-in')]//span[@class='gejrB'])[last()]/../..")
    print(textg)
    print(4)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`

Comment: how can i send you my python file? your email?

Comment: actually i am not able to find that classes gejrB and _1gL0z in inspect element , where are they ? are they classes of a particular chat or something else?

Comment: i searched in inspect element ,(ctrl + F) but no search matches for this classes

Comment: I'm sorry, but I will not give you my email

Comment: ok no problem , then what is the solution for this  to get emoji from whatsapp chat and and send that emoji to sender by python selenium ? plz help me

Comment: If my previous suggestions didn't help I don't know. Don't have more ideas for now